# Joomla Jforms page_url issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, joomla

Tried to retrieve page url (Jforms EMAIL option) after form submission but **form_data:page_url**
variable doesn't produce any output at the email.
**form_data:page_title** doesn't either. There is a Javascript which I believe retrieve URL. I have tried to use **Alert(vhref)** at the bottom of the script and it return URL pointing to the existing form at the popup window. I need it to be URL of submission result form which is automatically appear (Redirect to->Submitted data 'event') on the screen after form submission. My objective is to have this URL to be included into the email sent.  Joomla 3.4.3 , JForms 0.4.4
BR
oleg

```js
     
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 //Secure the user navigation on the page, in order preserve datas.
 var holdForm = false;
 window.onbeforeunload = function closeIt(){ if (holdForm) return false;};

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#<?php echo $formHash ?>").validationEngine();
  
           /*  var vhref = jQuery(location).attr('href',"submission/submissiondetails/"+"&cid"), */
         var  vhref = jQuery(location).attr('href'),
          vtitle = jQuery(this).attr('title'),
       hrefInput = jQuery("#<?php echo $formHash ?>").find('[name="jform[page_url]"]'),
      titleInput = jQuery("#<?php echo $formHash ?>").find('[name="jform[page_title]"]');
  
  if(hrefInput.val() == ''){
   hrefInput.val(vhref);
  }
  
  if(titleInput.val() == ''){
   titleInput.val(vtitle);
  }

 });
```